# Angular2 http.post, sending request inside header

Tags: javascript, angular

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
let myReq = { FirstName: "AB", LastName: "CD"}

let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
const url = 'http://myurl.com';
return this.http.post(url, options)
        .map(res => res.json());
```

> How can I inject json request (`myReq` variable) inside header as part of this post request.

Answer (score 1):

try like below code :

```
addBook() {

  let books = [
      { id: 1, name: 'Core Java' },
      { id: 2, name: 'Angular 2' },
      { id: 3, name: 'Hibernate' }
    ];

    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post(this.url, book, options)
               .map(this.extractData)
               .catch(this.handleErrorObservable);
}
```

Comment: i hope this will work for you, if it work please right as a solution.